# Convert U1 array to int in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, integer

I have the following array "class_id"

```
array([[array(['2'], 
  dtype='<U1')],
   [array(['3'], 
  dtype='<U1')],
   [array(['2'], 
  dtype='<U1')],
   ..., 
   [array(['2'], 
  dtype='<U1')],
   [array(['2'], 
  dtype='<U1')],
   [array(['2'], 
  dtype='<U1')]], dtype=object)
```

When I'm using the function:

class_id.astype(int)

I get the following error:

```
   ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-124-3ad39bf87e7d> in <module>()
----> 1 class_id.astype(int)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I would like to get the following array:

```
array([[1],
   [2],
   [1],
   ..., 
   [1],
   [1],
   [1]])
```

Which function should I use?

Comment: Can you please share a method of creating class_id array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an array of lists of array, you need to drop one *layer/dimension* to get your desired output; You can try this:

```
import numpy as np
np.array([s[0].astype(int) for s in class_id])

#array([[2],
#       [3],
#       [2],
#       [2],
#       [2],
#       [2]])
```

---

```
class_id = array([[array(['2'], 
  dtype='<U1')],
   [array(['3'], 
  dtype='<U1')],
   [array(['2'], 
  dtype='<U1')],
   [array(['2'], 
  dtype='<U1')],
   [array(['2'], 
  dtype='<U1')],
   [array(['2'], 
  dtype='<U1')]], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 0):

To recreate your array, I have to use:

```
array = np.array
In [460]: alist = [[array(['2'], 
     ...:   dtype='<U1')],
     ...:    [array(['3'], 
     ...:   dtype='<U1')],
     ...:    [array(['2'], 
     ...:   dtype='<U1')],
     ...:    [array(['2'], 
     ...:   dtype='<U1')],
     ...:    [array(['2'], 
     ...:   dtype='<U1')],
     ...:    [array(['2'], 
     ...:   dtype='<U1')]]
In [461]: arr = np.zeros((6,1), dtype=object)
In [462]: arr[:,0] = alist
In [463]: arr
Out[463]: 
array([[[array(['2'], 
      dtype='<U1')]],
       [[array(['3'], 
      dtype='<U1')]],
       [[array(['2'], 
      dtype='<U1')]],
       [[array(['2'], 
      dtype='<U1')]],
       [[array(['2'], 
      dtype='<U1')]],
       [[array(['2'], 
      dtype='<U1')]]], dtype=object)
```

A simple copy n paste strips out the inner array definitions:

```
array([[['2']],    # (6,1,1) shape

       [['3']],
       ...
       [['2']]], dtype=object)
```

Removing one level of [] with `arr[:,0]`, I can join the arrays with concatenate, and easily convert the `U1` array to `int` with one call to `astype`.

```
In [464]: np.concatenate(arr[:,0])
Out[464]: 
array([['2'],
       ['3'],
       ['2'],
       ['2'],
       ['2'],
       ['2']], 
      dtype='<U1')
In [465]: np.concatenate(arr[:,0]).astype(int)
Out[465]: 
array([[2],
       [3],
       [2],
       [2],
       [2],
       [2]])
```